# How to specify a default value for Django's TextField in South?

Tags: django, django-south

I added a TextField to a model whose corresponding table had already been created in the database. As I ran South, I got the following message:

> Since you are adding this field, you MUST specify a default value to
>   use for existing rows. Would you like to:
>   1. Quit now, and add a default to the field in models.py
>   2. Specify a one-off value to use for existing columns now

I selected choice 2) and gave it a default string value. But no matter what string values I gave, it just responded *"Invalid Choice"*.

Am I doing anything wrong in specifying a default value for TextField in South? Or is this a bug?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of South do you use? It works for me with 0.7.3

Comment: It seems the only time when South says "Invalid choice" is when it asks to choose option 1. or 2. and you enter invalid number.

Comment: Andrey - Good point. That was the exact stupid mistake that I made. Thanks for pointing that out. it was a long day you know~
You can go ahead post a solution and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only time when South says "Invalid choice" is when it asks to choose option 1. or 2. and you enter invalid number.